# Finding the largest possible scaling factor for squares that are box packed given the dimensions of the box

Tags: javascript, algorithm, computational-geometry

My problem is as follows:

I have a set of values `V1, V2, ... Vn`
I have a function `f(V) = g * V`, where `g` is a scaling factor, that maps these values to another set of values `A1, A2, ... An`. These values correspond to areas of squares. 
I also have `W` (width) and `H` (height) variables. And finally, I have a box packing algorithm ([This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078959/an-approach-to-implement-rectangular-bin-packing/21079042#21079042) to be specific), that takes the `W` and `H` variables, and the `A1 ... An` areas, and tries to find a way to pack the areas into a box of size `W x H`. If the areas `A` are not too big, and the box packing algorithm successfully manages to fit the areas into the box, it will return the positions of the squares (the left-top coordinates, but this is not relevant). If the areas are too big, it will return nothing.

Given the values `V` and the dimensions of the box `W` and `H`, what is the highest value of `g` (the scaling factor in `f(V)`) that still fits the box?

I have tried to create an algorithm that initally sets `g` to `(W x H) / sum(V1, V2, ... Vn)`. If the values `V` are distributed in such a way that they fit exactly into the box without leaving any space in between, this would give me a solution instantly. In reality this never happens, but it seems like a good starting point. With this initial value of `g` I would calculate the values `A` which are then fed to the box packing algorithm. The box packing algorithm will fail (return nothing), after which I decrease `g` by `0.01` (a completely arbitrary value established by trial and error) and try again. This cycle repeats until the box packing algorithm succeeds.

While this solution works, I feel like there should be faster and more accurate ways to determine `g`. For example, depending on how big `W` and `H` compared to the sum of the values `V`, it seems that there should be a way to determine a better value than `0.01`, because if the difference is extremely big the algorithm would take really long, while if the difference is extremely small it would be very fast but very crude. In addition, I feel like there should be a more efficient method than just brute-forcing it like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're on a good trail with your method I think !

I think you shouldn't decrease your value by a fixed amount but rather try to approach the value by ever smaller steps.

It's good because you have a good starting value. First you could decrease g by something like `0.1 * g`, check if your packing succeeds, if not, continue to decrease with same step, else if it packs correctly increase g with a smaller step (like `step = step / 2`)

At some point your steps will become very small and you can stop searching (defining "small" is up to you)

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search approach. If you have two values of g, so that for one (g1) packing exists and for second (g2) packing doesn't exist, try value on half way h=(g1+g2)/2. If packing exists for h you get new larger final g, and you can make same check with h and g2. If packing doesn't exist you can make same check with values g1 and h.

With each step, interval of possible result max value, is halfed. You can get final result as precise as you like, with more iterations.